# How to have a selectable background together with a certain color background?

Tags: android, colors, selection, background-color

I know that you would get a selectable (highlight/ripple) background for a view using this:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But what if I want a certain color background together with the ripple/highlight, what do I do?

(I'm hoping for a few lines of code **not involving creating separate drawables** which is very inelegant)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />  <--your custom color-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

And then

```
android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
```

in your button